# Best way of storing large pre-formatted text to be displayed on a website?

Tags: database, text, web

I have about 21 text files with pre-formatted html content(text,images with html markup). I am creating a website that would display these text-files with the correct format. Also, the no. of files (21 files as of now) is most likely to keep on increasing. I would like some help as to

- Should I create an individual page for each text file?
- Should I store all the text files in a database and retrieve and display them from the database?
- Read the html content from the files on the file system and display them accordingly?
- Or is there any other better way of doing the same thing(possibly XML)?

Comment: If you are using the Microsoft stack I would highly recommend using the Composite C1 CMS system.  I have been using it for this purpose and it is a dream.  Allows you to switch your data from being stored within a database or an xml file structure too.  No point reinventing the wheel.  Like the answer given by @Zsolt Szilagy on here suggests - a CMS is probs the best way to go. Almost any one would do, I just thought I would recommend Composite :)

Comment: @Sean I would look into Composite. Thx for the reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are creating is a so-called content management system, short cms. Wordpress, Drupal, and many others are examples.

Creating single pages is the worst idea: You will have to update them all for every change.
XML is not that good either: You don´t want to parse ALL the texts  to extract a single text on every visit (performance).

Although your task can be achieved by storing single text files, **I advise to go with the database**. As your CMS will grow, you will have the option to add further data. (E.g. you will add a meta-keywords tag, or an active/inactive-flag, a title field and so on.)

While one day you might think about caching database for performance, even on the slowest shared host MySql gracefully handles sever hundred queries per second.

**EDIT: What to store in DB?**

You don´t want everything in DB. Besides CSS, Images and JS being regular files (cached by browsers), you will have your header, footer and navigation in html. (Or smarty .tpl files - check it out.  Not everyone likes it, I do.) What belongs into DB are the "content parts.

*Ask yourself two questions:*

- If I change that part, will that change be visible on more that
  one page? If yes, it belongs to a layout html file.
- If I want to give access to someone who writes my content - would
  I grant him access to that part? If not, it´s a layout file.

Typically, your page consists of

- header (logo, search, login etc.)
- navigation (categories etc.)
- sidebar (news, gadgets, further navigation)
- content (in database).
- footer (link to imprint etc.)

You might want to check out some established CMS system before attempting to make your own. You might get valuable insights.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Just one more question: Do i store the entire page content with the html markup in the database?